# What does this Truffle onConnect error mean?

Tags: truffle, ubuntu

I've been following a tutorial to set up a simple voting application just for experimentation purposes but after installing truffle, it seems it won't connect.

Heres the error I'm getting when I try anything with truffle

[image]

Literally any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Check the last version of Node.js that you have installed.

Older versions of Node.js (older than 7.6) does not support Async functions.

See this thread on Stackoverflow: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token function - Async Await Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815790/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-function-async-await-nodejs)

Check this link for more information about the [different ways to upgrade Node.js](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/)